# Proof that at most one of $e\pi$ and $e+\pi$ can be rational

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function, pi, transcendental-numbers, rationality-testing

$e$ and $\pi$ are rather peculiar numbers. It turns out that, in 
addition to being irrational numbers, they are also transcendental 
numbers. Basically, a number is transcendental if there are no 
polynomials with rational coefficients that have that number as a 
root.

Clearly, $p(x) = (x-e)(x-\pi)$ is a polynomial whose roots are $e$ and $\pi$, 
so its coefficients cannot all be rational, by the definition of 
transcendental numbers. Expanding that expression, we get

$$(x-e)(x-\pi) = x^2 - (e+      \pi)x + e\pi$$

This means that $1, -(e+\pi), e\pi$ cannot all be rational. If all the 
coefficients were rational, we would have found a polynomial with 
rational coefficients that had $e$ and $\pi$ as roots, and that has been 
proven impossible already. Hermite proved that $e$ is transcendental in 
1873, and Lindemann proved that $\pi$ is transcendental in 1882. In fact, 
Lindemann's proof was similar to Hermite's proof and was based on the 
fact that $e$ is also transcendental.

In other words, at most one of $e+\pi$ and $e\pi$ is rational. (We know 
that they cannot both be rational, so that's the most we can say).
Are there any more conditions required for this proof to be correct?

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Using that $e$ and $\pi$ are transcendental, to prove irrationality of either $e+\pi$ or $e\pi$ seems like overkill to me, but the proof looks sound.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. What prevents $e+π$ and $eπ$ from both being irrational at the same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do not really need to use the fact that both $\pi$ and $e$ are trascendental numbers. If both $e\pi$ and $\pi+e$ were rational numbers, then $e$ would be a quadratic irrational, so its continued fraction would be eventually periodic due to [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction). However, the [continued fraction of $e$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/eContinuedFraction.html) is well-known:

$$ e = [2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,\ldots] $$
and its coefficients are unbounded.

Answer (score 11):

The proof is correct. For a nit-pick, you should say you have a *non-zero* polynomial.

Note that it would even suffice to know that at least one of $\pi$ and $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: Are you certain that knowing "at least one of $\pi,e$ is transcendental" is sufficient?  What if both were transcendental and just happened to sum and multiply to rationals?

Comment: @abiessu what I meant to say is that for your argument to work  you'd only need to know one of them is transcendental.