# Which is greater $e^{\pi}$ or $\pi^e$?

Tags: exponential-function, pi

Recently I asked a question on Maths SE

[Proof that at most one of $e\pi$ and $e+\pi$ can be rational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095416/proof-that-at-most-one-of-e-pi-and-e-pi-can-be-rational)

after solving this one one I was thinking whether $e^\pi$ is greater or $\pi^e$ ?
On calculating exact values upto 7 digits i got these values

$e^{\pi} =23.1406926$................and

$\pi^e =22.4591577$...............

So practically 
I proved that $e^\pi$ is greater than $\pi^e$.
But without finding the values If we want to find it , I want to know how to find it ....
Suppose there are few type of sim like which one is greater from $17^{51}$ or $51^{17}$ , so we use Binomial Theorem , but here I didn't got any idea how to prove it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$e^\pi<=>\pi^e\iff e^{\frac1e}<=>\pi^{\frac1\pi}$$

Now find the extreme value(s) of $\displaystyle x^{\frac1x}$

Comment: if x is negative then would this condition be satisfied ?

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia, For $x<0,x^{1/x}$ may not remain real, right?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/comparing-pie-and-e-pi

Answer (score 2):

your inequality is equivalent to $\frac{\pi}{\ln (\pi)}>e$ use the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$

Answer (score -1):

**HINT :**

Use $log$, which is increasing on $\mathbb{R^+}$ (then $log(a) > log (b)  \implies a>b$ for instance).